# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\coder.accdb"
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Student Information ('" + txtid.Text + "','" + txtroll.Text + "','" + txtfname.Text + "','" + txtlname.Text + "','" + txtpclass.Text + "','" + txtpname.Text + "','" + txtmname.Text + "','" + txtfoccupation.Text + "','" + txtmoccupation.Text + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "','" + txtcontact.Text + "','" + txtlandl.Text + "','" + txtpschool.Text + "') ", con)

```
   Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

    If (i >= 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Data saved Successfully", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Data not  saved Successfully", "Unsuccessfull!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)


    End If
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a really bad way to write SQL code. You should learn how to use parameterised queries to avoid various issues.

Comment: Avoid using spaces and other special characters in your database identifiers. If you must use them then you also must escape those names. For Access that means wrapping them in brackets.

Comment: When posting code, please take the time to format it properly.  Your code is unreadable as posted.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement is missing the VALUES keyword. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb208861(v=office.12)

```
insert into myTable values (val1, val2, val3, ...)
```

Or:

```
insert into myTable (col1, col2, col3, ...) values (col1, col2, col3, ...)
```